# Issue with setter and LazyLoad Session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, setter, lazy-loading

Preface, I'm completely new to using Spring but have been working with it and kind of figuring it out as I go. I'm using Java Basic Spring.

I have an issue where I have an object that contains, in addition to a number of things a Many To One Relationship representing players at a game. It is a List.

Testing this with our Controller has revealed an issue with the setter of this List, specifically:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.pokerface.pokerapi.game.GameState.players; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.pokerface.pokerapi.game.GameState.players


public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
    this.players=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Player p:players){
        this.players.add(p);
    }
}
```

So I undo my changes to have the basic setter:

```
public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
      this.players=players;
}
```

But now I'm running into the issue that this collection when put into or pulled from the database, sometimes, returns the exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.pokerface.pokerapi.game.GameState.players, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I am deeply out of my element, so I apologize if I don't have the appropriate information up. What kind of setter should be implemented here? Is it even a problem with the setter? Thank you.

When I examine it in debug, if I check all the stored objects in the repository, they pull out but players states "Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException'

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access before loading but after the DB is closed

Comment: What closes the DB? and how can I reopen it?

Comment: How can I tell from this snippet of code? Try creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the setter. It seems to me that you're accessing the setter outside of a @Transactional context. In that case you're unable to access Lazy Loaded Entities after loading the object containing your players from the database.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative